# Why can't I pass the function directly into replace method?

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

I simply can't understand why the second and the third lines of output differs one from another:

```js
alphabet_ASCII = '';
for (i=65; i<=90; i++) {
  alphabet_ASCII += i;
}
alphabet_ASCII += '<br>';

document.body.innerHTML += alphabet_ASCII;



document.body.innerHTML += 
  alphabet_ASCII.replace(/\d{2}/g, x=>String.fromCharCode(x));

document.body.innerHTML += 
  alphabet_ASCII.replace(/\d{2}/g, String.fromCharCode);
```

What's the difference between `x=>String.fromCharCode(x)` and `String.fromCharCode`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `String.fromCharCode` accepts multiple arguments, and `replace` calls the callback with more than just the one argument you're expecting: It calls the callback with:

- All matching text
- The contents of any capture groups (if any)
- The index (offset) at which this match occurred
- The whole string being acted on

[More on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

So in your second example, `String.fromCharCode` gets more arguments than in your first, and does its best with them. On the first callback, `String.fromCharCode` gets `"65", 0, "6566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990"` and so returns `"A\u0000\u0000"` (because the second argument is 0 and the third is invalid). On the second pass it gets `"66", 2, "6566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990"` and returns `"B\u0002\u0000"`, etc.

Comment: I didn't know about the third and fourth args.. Nice to know, I will accept when possible

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes: Truthfully, neither did I, but when I saw the question I thought "I bet it's for the same reason you can't do that with `forEach`..." and looked it up. :-)

Comment: Just to point you from where my question was [originated](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/71735/48943)